# Why does pygame freeze for me?

Tags: python, pygame

**Here is my code**

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
from pygame import *
from sys import *

pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.time.Clock()

runGame = True

while runGame == True:

    currentKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if currentKeys[K_ESCAPE] == True:
        runGame = False

    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)

pygame.quit()
sys.quit()
```

**I just wanted a display that closed on Esc key press. What's wrong with this code?**

Comment: Can you explain "freeze". What is the observed behavior. Do you start the display? Have a look  [here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/pygame-physics-simulation/creating-pygame-window/)

Comment: It's alright, thank you. I should've specified but I've found a suggestion that works for me now anyway.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are creating many clocks by calling `pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)`. Usually, you create one clock using the line `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` and then you call `clock.tick(60)`. But, your code may be okay too.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not doing that on purpose, I just don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the event queue fills up and so the window won't react to events from your operating system/window manager.

Make sure to call [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) (or [`pygame.event.pump`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump)) in your game loop.

From [`pygame.event.pump`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system. If you are not using other event functions in your game, you should call pygame.event.pump() to allow pygame to handle internal actions.
>
> This function is not necessary if your program is consistently processing events on the queue through the other pygame.event functions.
>
> There are important things that must be dealt with internally in the event queue. The main window may need to be repainted or respond to the system. If you fail to make a call to the event queue for too long, the system may decide your program has locked up.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly.